# os.popen().readlines() showing permission denied

Tags: python, readline

I am trying to use os.popen("command").readlines() but there are some paths where I don't have access and code is printing for that path "permission denied" .
I want to use the code in such a way that it should print the line if permission is there or if permission is not there then it has to move to next folder without printing anything.

Comment: That's just returning whatever `command` wrote to stdout. What is `command` and what are you really trying to do?

Comment: os.popen('grep \"(text)"').readlines(). Using this command I am collecting specific lines of the text file. And pass keyword from that line to some other function. But If I dont have permission to open  that file then it is showing permission denied. Aim here is that it should not print "permission denied"

Comment: [`os.access`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) should be able to check that for you. For example, you can check if you have rights to read a file: `os.access("/etc/passwd", os.R_OK)`  -> `True`, and if you can write to it: `os.access("/etc/passwd", os.W_OK)` -> `False`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if code gives error then you can always use `try/except` to catch it and skip to next value.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title and sentences. This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.